# "Orientation cube" in three JS

Tags: camera, three.js

I'd like to make an orientation view cube in three JS.

The ["View Cube"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnsFR.png)
 is in a scene using Orthographic Camera and **OrthographicTrackballControls**.

What I actually do is create a view cube:

```
gizmoBox = new THREE.Object3D();

for (var x = -1; x <= 1; x+=1) {
    for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y+=1) {
        for (var z = -1; z <= 1; z+=1) {
            if (/* is a corner coordinate */) {
                corner = new THREE.Mesh(...);
                ...
                gizmoBox.add(corner);
            } else if (/*is a border coordinate*/) {
                edge = new THREE.Mesh( ... );
                ...
                gizmoBox.add(edge);
            } else if (/*is a side coordinate */) {
                side = new THREE.Mesh(...)
                ...
                gizmoBox.add(side);
                /*here, i added some text : FRONT, BACK, ...*/
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And scale it to be in the upper right corner of the camera:

```
function render() {
    ...
    var vec = new THREE.Vector3( 0.0145 / camera.zoom, 0.012 / camera.zoom, 0.01 / camera.zoom );
    vec.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
    gizmoBox.position.copy( vec );
    gizmoBox.scale.set(0.0015 / camera.zoom, 0.0015 / camera.zoom, 0.0015 / camera.zoom);
    ...
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Then I want to use the position of every parts of the view cube (before scaling) as "reference point" in the the scene to make the rotation. So I added this function in **OrthographicTrackballControls**.

```
this.rotateViewCube = function (refPoint) {
    _rotateEnd.copy(refPoint);
    _this.rotateCamera();
};
```

But it doesn't work correctly, the camera move but not as I expected. Someone as an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.

I get the "reference point" form the clicked part of the View Cube, then I modify the default camera position in **OrthographicTrackballControls** (refered by *position0*). And finally I reset it.

```
var position = intersects[0].object.refPoint;
controls.position0.copy(position);
controls.reset();
```